# Integral with equal limits where the function goes to infinity

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

My differential equation is as following:
$$
r^{\prime}\left[x\right]=\frac{\left(1-g\left[x\right]\right)r\left[x\right]}{x}+\frac{r\left[x\right]^{2}}{x}
$$
I have the general solution of a linear dif equation:
$$r\left[x\right]=\frac{e^{\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\left(1-g\left[t\right]\right)}{t}dt}}{C-\int_{0}^{x}\left(e^{\int_{0}^{s}\frac{\left(1-g\left[t\right]\right)}{t}dt}\frac{1}{s}\right)ds},$$
where $g[x]$ is a normally behaving function (with $g[0]=k>0$), and all functions here are defined on $x \in [0,\infty)$.
The problem is that my initial condition is $r[0]=0$. It seems that the integrand goes to infinity due to $1/t$, while the limits of the integration go to $\infty$.

I know that simply saying that the integrands go to zero doesn't work, because $r[x]=ax$ and $g[x]=ax$ is a valid example. At the same time, if I assume that the integrals just should go to zero,   the general solution then is $r[0]=\frac{e^0}{C-0}$, entailing $C\rightarrow \infty$.

Thanks in advance! I love you guys.

Comment: Your equation has a regular singularity at $x=0$, the corresponding approximation is $xr'(x)=(1-g(0))r(x)$ leads to $r(x)\approx Cx^{1-g(0)}$.

Comment: $r(x)=0$ is a solution that satisfies the initial condition $r(0)=0$.